# On Click Event JS Loader Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cordova

So I got a wordpress website, tailored and CSSed to work as a mobile application on apache cordova and everythign is working fine.

Since it's highly reliable on the inAppBrowser the user doesn't get to see the browser loader after clicking a tile or a button and might think that the application is not responding.

My question is, is there a way to make any click event in wordpress's home page generate a spinner or a loader without having to mess with the php files?

If not then how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try click event on button id:

```
$('#button_ID').click(function(){
  $('#loader_img').show(); // Show Loader
  $.ajax({
    Your Code ...
   success:function(result){
   $('#loader_img').hide();  //Hide Loader
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok that sounds right, but where should that be put to work? Because that's the main question? In the regular WordPress script editor?

Comment: Create JS file and add code in that file and in functions.php include that js file using wp_enqueue_scripts() function